# How to perform such filter queries in mongoengine on nested dicts or arrays contained in dict with python?

Tags: python, mongodb

Say I have the following dict object:

```
{
    "a": "value of a",
    "somedict": {
        "someinfo": [
            {
                "name": "Jordan",
                "food": [
                    "fries",
                    "coke",
                    "drink"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

If I wanted to apply a query filter in python using mongoengine, how would I do it? I see in the documentation you can do things like:

```
sample_objs_filter = Sample.objects(a='value of a')
```

But how would I filter on say

```
1) "name='Jordan'" 
2)'food' contains 'fries'?
```

If mongoengine cant do it, is there some other mongo library thats better at accomplishing this?

Comment: I dont know what to try... the docs for mongoengine seem too generic for the cases I need.

Comment: @Seiverence: did you read the Mongoengine docs on [Query operators](http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/querying.html#query-operators)?  Plenty of options there :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd suggest reading more about mongodb's [dot notation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29) about how you can query / look into objects and return matching documents.

As you can't use a dot as a keyword argument [mongoengine](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine) follows the django orm style of double underscores:

```
1) Sample.objects(somedict__someinfo__name='Jordan')
2) Sample.objects(somedict__someinfo__food='Fries')
```

Answer (score 6):

The mongoengine dot notation can be used within mongoengine in the following way:
Sample.objects(`__raw__` = "***name_of_db_field***.**key**":"value_to_match")

Say your class is:

```
Class data(Document):
   field = DictField(db_field="dbfield")
```

And your you store the dict:

```
{
    "a": "value of a",
    "somedict": {
        "someinfo": [
            {
                "name": "Jordan",
                "food": [
                    "fries",
                    "coke",
                    "drink"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The keys act as objects attributes, so can query as such:

```
data.objects(field__a = "value of a")
```

that reads the same as

```
data.objects(__raw__ = {'dbfield.a' : 'value of a'})
```

For nested items, the `__` works as the dot. Example

```
data.objects(field__somedict__someinfo__name="Jordan")
```

reads the same as:

```
data.objects(__raw__ = {'dbfield.somedict.someinfo.name' : 'Jordan'})
```